# How to pass "in-tuple multiple arguments" without violating pep8?

Tags: python, pep8, multiple-arguments

I have a game class and I need to pass screen width and height into `pygame.display.set_mode()` in `__init__ method`.
It requires **a tuple**, for example - `pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))`.

I have also a second class named Settings from which I import width and height.

If I need to pass **long name** attributes inside a tuple, is it okay to write these double parentheses the way I did below not to exceed 79 chars? I'm not sure because I've never seen the double parentheses case in PEP8, only single.

```
def __init__(self):
    """Initialize the game, create game resources."""
    pygame.init()
    self.settings = Settings()
    self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((
        self.settings.screen_width,
        self.settings.screen_height
    ))
```

Comment: This is opinion-based. If you think it's readable then use it.

Comment: Does the automated pep-8 checker flag this as a violation? (If not: Is there any other concrete, practical reason you're concerned about this being a convention violation?)

Comment: In general, if you want your code formatting to follow purely mechanical rules, I would suggest using [black](https://github.com/psf/black) to enforce that.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I'm new to Python and I'm using PyCharm. If by pep8 checker you mean yellow underline, then no, it doesn't flag this as a violation.

Comment: I don't think double parentheses are violating PEP 8 but if you want to be sure, you can create a variable `rect` and use it like `pygame.display.set_mode(rect)`

Comment: I meant the command line tool named `pep8`. PyCharm may or may not integrate that tool; I don't use PyCharm -- but see https://pypi.org/project/pep8/

Comment: The `pep8` tool has been renamed to `pycodestyle`. But it does not return any violation for this piece of code

Comment: @Matthias This is a question about compliance with a style guide, which presumably has a published preference. It is not opinion-based to ask about style guide compliance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [pycodestyle](https://pypi.org/project/pycodestyle/) to check that your code is PEP8 compliant.

If I copy-paste your code in a `settings.py` file, I can use

```bash
pip install pycodestyle
pycodestyle --show-source --show-pep8 settings.py
```

which does not return anything, so you're good.

However, [as mentioned by CharlesDuffy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76898703/how-to-pass-in-tuple-multiple-arguments-without-violating-pep8#comment135564093_76898703), I suggest you to use a code formatter such as [black](https://pypi.org/project/black/) to ensure consistent and PEP8 compliant code formatting.